# Is it possible to "get records older than N days" in CQL?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a requirement which requires to fetch all records older than N days. As Cassandra doesn't support the GETDATE() which is available in SQL and helps to achieve the same task, what could be the possible solution in CQL? The SQL query is given below for reference,

`Select * from table where created_date < GETDATE() - 'NDays'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a native CQL function `CURRENTDATE()` which returns the system time in date format but there are no operators in the CQL grammar which allows that level of manipulation.

Our general recommendation is to perform the calculation within your application then feed the result to your CQL query.

As a side note, retrieving multiple partitions based on a range filter is a bad access pattern for Cassandra.

Cassandra is designed for high-velocity reads at internet scale, particularly retrieving single partitions really fast. If you need to retrieve multiple records in a query, there's a good chance that (a) you have an analytics use case (instead of OLTP), (b) you got your data model wrong, or (c) both. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question given the perspective of Erick's answer, "yes," as long as you've built your table to support that query.  I wrote an article about doing that a couple of years ago, using arithmetic operators and date types in Apache Cassandra 4.0: [Arithmetic Operators in Apache Cassandra 4.0](https://medium.com/building-the-open-data-stack/arithmetic-operators-in-apache-cassandra-4-0-c5a3185d683)

If I built a table for data about "nerd holidays," the structure would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE nerd_holidays (
  year_bucket BIGINT,
  event_date DATE,
  name TEXT,
  id UUID,
  PRIMARY KEY ((year_bucket), event_date, id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (event_date ASC, id ASC);
```

Then I could pull data for the next 30 days like this:

```
> SELECT event_date, name
  FROM nerd_holidays WHERE year_bucket=2023
  AND event_date >= toDate(now())
  AND event_date < toDate(now()) + 30d;

 event_date | name
------------+----------------------------
 2023-04-30 | International Tabletop Day
 2023-05-04 |              Star Wars Day

(2 rows)
```